# How do units get Altitude Training in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Sometimes my units in Civilization 5 get "altitude training" promotion which makes movement faster. However, I have no idea where it comes from. Is it randomly assigned to some units or is there some way to improve the chances of getting that promotion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Units gain the Altitude Training promotion when they enter a hex beside Mt. Kilimanjaro.